# Android app crashing after adding Firebase authentication

Tags: android, firebase, mobile, firebase-authentication

I am working on developing an android app using firebase but The app works fine without firebase the worst thing is android studio doesn't show the error,  but the app crashes after adding firebase Authentication. what would be the problem? Any help is appreciated.

I tried changing the version of firebase, tried changing Gradle file and created different projects in firebase to see if that make a difference nothing changed

```
package com.example.manual;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText e1,e2;

FirebaseAuth mAuth ;
FirebaseUser currentUser;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit)
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.

    if(currentUser == null){


        Intent startIntent = new 
 Intent(MainActivity.this,RegisterActivity.class);
        startActivity(startIntent);
        finish();
    }

    }



}


Gradele file 
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.manual"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
```

core:3.0.2'
   }

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'




Project manual file

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }

}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

in the firebase assistant window, it shows it is connected but still the 
    app crashes every time I try to run it on my real device? please help 
    don't judge me I just started teaching myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to `'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'` and `'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'` in your gradle file.

Also would the app still crash if you commented out `startActivity(startIntent);
        finish();`?